# css div float layout

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've coming from designing layouts with tables and now finally trying it out using divs.

But I still can't get the layout right. It's not as obvious as tables.
For example, I have:

```
var html_output = 
"<div id='infoPlanet' style='width:400px;'>"+
"   <div id='gambarPlanet' style='padding: 0px; width:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right: 200px;'>"+
"       <IMG SRC='\\Planets\\planet"+gambarPlanet+ ".jpg'>"+
"   </div>"+ 
"   <div id='kadarSehari' style='padding: 0px; width:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right: 200px;'>"+
"       <table class='kadarPlanet'>"+
"       <tr><td>Kadar Kelahiran</td><td>"+kadarmanusia+"</td></tr>"+
"       <tr><td>Kadar Perlombongan</td><td>"+kadarkristal+"</td></tr>"+
"       <tr><td>Kadar Penjanaan</td><td>"+kadarnadir+"</td></tr>"+
"       </table>"+
"   </div>"+
"</div>"
```

But what comes out of that is gambarPlanet is on the left, and kadarSehari is on the right.
How do I make kadarSehari go below gambarPlanet?

I have changed width of gambarPlanet to 300px to make gambarPlanet.width + kadarSehari.width = 300+200 > 400, but kadarSehari just goes over the main div (infoPlanet) right boundary. kadarSehari div does not want to go below gambarPlanet.

I've tried gambarPlanet.style.float="top" and kadarSehari.style.float="bottom" and still nothing happens. I've tried position: absolute, position: static, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

If you don't mind, what should be the structure I should write if I want two divs:
1) appear next to each other (like what I am currently outputting, but that's just luck, I don't understand the mechanism behind it)
2) appear one on top of each other.

And if I want 4 divs : left middle-left middle-right right, how should I write the divs?

I can write this in 5 mins with , and it has taken me 6 hours to try code it with divs, and I have nothing I can go on with at the moment.

If you can help, please show me what to do. Hope I Can leran something.

Comment: Make a jsFiddle to help us resolve the problem!

Comment: I tried, but i don't understand how to get jsFiddle to work.
I can read examples on jsFiddle, but dont know how to do one myself. Sorry, am n00b beginner here. But anyway, the accepted answer below taught me how to solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two divs to be next to each other you just need add `float:left;`:

```
<div id="infoPlanet" style="width:400px;">
    <div id="gambarPlanet" style="width:200px;float:left;"></div>
    <div id="kadarSehari" style="width:200px;float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

If you want the second one to be under the first one use:

```
<div id="infoPlanet" style="width:200px;">
    <div id="gambarPlanet" style="width:200px;"></div>
    <div id="kadarSehari" style="width:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

For a working demo see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NmAL/)

Comment: Thank you for this really clear minimalist answer. I thought I already had this, but it didn't work. I then typed one by one, and discovered that I had a document.getElementById("gambarPlanet").style.position=....  somewhere and it was that which screwed up the formatting. I thought that "position" was needed, but apparently from your example, its not. So I have learned a great deal from your minimalist example. Thank you so much.